# Replace non-ASCII character in Python: eg, ' vs. ’

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I wan't `you’ll` to be reduced to `you ll` (not `youll`). This is what I'm doing:

```
>>> clean = "you'll"
>>> import string
>>> clean = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, clean)
>>> print clean
you'll

>>> clean = "you’ll" 
>>> clean = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, clean)
>>> print clean
youll
```

This is what I tried:

```
>>> clean = "you'll"
>>> clean =clean.replace('\'',' ')
>>> print clean
you ll
>>> clean = "you’ll"
>>> clean =clean.replace('’',' ')
>>> print clean
you ll
```

This works fine, but when I put it in my script:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file sc.py on line 177, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

So, I added to the very top of my script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But get

```
clean =clean.replace('’',' ')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm a bit out of ideas.

Comment: 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)

Comment: Still get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: It works from the terminal (as shown), but in my script it doesn't

Comment: Thanks bro! Your question made me realize that my system is soo messed up that I needed 20mins to search for a simple file!

Comment: At least you keep track of the fixes!

Comment: Yeah. Luck was on your side that I hadn't deleted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `decode` the string

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
clean = "you’ll".decode('utf-8')
clean = clean.replace('’'.decode('utf-8'),' ')
print clean
```

This `print`s

```
you ll
```

which is as expected

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the best answer, but a simple solution is to just handle the exception:

```
clean2 = ""
for ch in clean:
    try:
        clean2 += " " if ch == "'" else clean2 += ch
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        clean2 += 'vs.'
```

Comment: Why? Such a round about route bro?

Comment: But an intelligent one also!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the apostrophe with a space, using `replace()`, like this:

```
print "you'll".replace("'", " ")
```

Prints `you ll`